# Display list of option choices in help text automatically in OptionParser

Tags: python, optionparser

I have an option in `OptionParser` that takes in a list of choices.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from optparse import OptionParser

def main():
    parser = OptionParser(usage="Usage: foo")  
    parser.add_option('-e', '--env',
                  type='choice',
                  action='store',
                  dest='environment',
                  choices=['prod', 'staging', 'test', 'dev'],
                  default='dev',
                  help='Environment to run on',)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run `--help` command, I see:

```
Usage: foo

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -e ENVIRONMENT, --env=ENVIRONMENT
                        Environment to run on
```

I'd like it so that my list of choices automatically shows up in environment's help text (and preferably even the default). Is there any way to access the `choices` object to be used to generate the help text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way would be something like:

```
choices = ['prod', 'staging', 'test', 'dev'] 
help = "Environment to run on (choose from: {!r})".format(choices)
parser.add_option('-e', '--env',
                  type='choice',
                  action='store',
                  dest='environment',
                  choices=choices,
                  default='dev',
                  help=help,)
```

which produces:

```
Usage: foo

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -e ENVIRONMENT, --env=ENVIRONMENT
                        Environment to run on (choose from: ['prod',
                        'staging', 'test', 'dev'])
```

You could put a bit more effort into the `help` assignment if you want the help to look neater!

Answer (score 2):

You can put `%default` into the help text and it will be expanded to the default value of that option ([see docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#generating-help)).

With choices, I'm afraid, you have to put them into a separate list and add manually. It allows to add explanations, though:

```
env_choices = [
  ('prod', 'production; use caution!'),
  ('test', 'used by testers, do not break')
  ('dev', 'developers\' safe playgroud')
]

# ...
choices = [name for name, _ in env_choices],
help = "Environment (defaults to %default); one of:\n %s" % (
         "\n\t".join(name + ": " + descr for name, descr in env_choices)  
       )
```